# Error path of site running on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a ASP.NET site running locally (localhost) on my Windows 7 computer. I have an error when loading one of the pages. The error is in an aspx.cs file and I can see how to fix it easy enough. But when I edit the source file nothing changes.

So I notice that on my machine the path to the file is C:\intetpub\wwwroot\folder\codefile.aspx.cs

But on the error message the path is e:\intetpub\wwwroot\User_Sites\folder\codefile.aspx.cs

I realize this must be a virtual directory used by the IIS (I assume) but cannot figure out why editing the code file on C: does not lead to it being loaded into the virtual directory when I run it.

I do not have a physical e: drive or User_Sites folder anywhere.

I realize this is probably a simple question but perhaps someone could point out a reference that explains this, or provide a simple explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the web server is using a version of the application that was built using the sources in e:... and not the version you are working on.

Try:

1. stopping the WWW publishing service
2. deleting the contents of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
3. deleting the bin folder of your application
4. building the application
5. start the WWW publishing service.